# what is the point of using these [input] and [output] functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I found this on a react-native excel export demo on GitHub , I don't get why these two functions were necessary `input`  and `output`  , why not just pass `wbout`  to `writeFile` directly , is this some functional programming type of stuff ?

```
const input = res => res;
const output = str => str;

const exportFile =()=> {
        //...some code 
        writeFile(file, output(wbout), 'ascii').then((res) =>{
             console.log("exportFile success", "Exported to " + file);
        }).catch((err) => { 
             console.log("exportFile Error", "Error " + err.message); 
        });
};
const importFile=()=> {
        readFile(DDP + "sheetjs.xlsx", 'ascii').then((res) => {
            /* parse file */
            const wb = XLSX.read(input(res), {type:'binary'});
             //...rest of coe
        })
}
```

> > demo:https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/9866dfc010338394e4cfcd33a9fbc15dae017ee5/demos/react/react-native.js

Comment: Both are just functions that return whats input.  It's maybe XLSX.read expects a function to return the data.

Comment: actually it expects a string but I see your point , my guess is that maybe the functions can be used or modify passed string in some cases for example   ```const input = res => res.trim();```

Comment: @Keith check Jérémie's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the header in a comment block:

```
// react-native-fetch-blob
/*
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
const { writeFile, readFile, dirs:{ DocumentDir } } = RNFetchBlob.fs;
const DDP = DocumentDir + "/";
const input = res => res.map(x => String.fromCharCode(x)).join("");
const output = str => str.split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0));
*/
```

in your case `input` or `output` are not necessary, but the author uses them when you remove the comments for `react-native-fetch-blob`.

The functions are here to have one code for two demos.